# When is a cyclotomic polynomial over a finite field a minimal polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

When is the cyclotomic polynomial $f(x)$ over a finite field $\mathrm{F}_q$ also the minimal polynomial of some element $\alpha \in \mathrm{F}_q$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, a polynomial $f\in F[X]$ is the minimal polynomial of its roots over $F$ if and only if $f$ is irreducible over $F$. Cyclotomic polynomials provide no exception.

However, while cyclotomic polymomials are irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, not all of them are irreducible when considered as a polynomial over a finite field.
For example, over $\mathbb F_2$ the $7$th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_7 = X^6 + X^5 + X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1$ factors into two factors of degree $3$:
$$
\Phi_7 = (X^3 + X + 1)(X^3 + X^2 + 1)
$$
Hence $\Phi_7\in\mathbb F_2[X]$ is not irreducible and therefore not the minimal polynomial of its roots.

**Note**: This was written as a response to an earlier version of the question.

Comment: Please explain it for the following example. Given finite field $\mathrm{F}_q$, I have a decomposition $x^n-1=\prod_{i=0}^{m-1}f_i(x)$ over $\mathrm{F}_q$, where all $f_i(x)$ are cyclotomic. I am not sure that all $f_i(x)$ are minimal polynomials for some elements from extension $[\mathrm{F}_q^r : \mathrm{F}_q]$, where $r$ is a smallest number that $n$ divides $q^r - 1$. What is wrong in that?

Comment: @PiotrSemenov: I've added information on cyclotomic polynomials over finite fields to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! So I did a mistake while suggesting that cyclotomic polynomials are also irreducible in case of finite fields.

Comment: @PiotrSemenov: Exactly!

Comment: +1: In some sense an even smaller counterexample is
$$\Phi_3(X)=X^2+X+1=(X-2)(X-4)\in\Bbb{F}_7[X].$$ Or even $\Phi_3(X)=(X-1)^2\in \Bbb{F}_3[X].$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: That's true. For my example, I decided to go with an example over $\mathbb F_2$. Here, the smallest reducible one is $\Phi_4 = (X + 1)^2$, which might be a bit misleading. So I ended up with $\Phi_7$.

Answer (score 18):

One can show that the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbf F_p$ precisely when $p$ has multiplicative order $\varphi(n)$ modulo $n$. This follows from the theory of cyclotomic extensions of $\mathbf Q$.

In particular, if $(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^\times$ is not cyclic (i.e. unless $n$ is an odd prime power, twice an odd prime power, or $n=2$ or $4$), then $\Phi_n(X)$ is reducible modulo *every* prime $p$, despite being irreducible over $\mathbf Q$!

Comment: Do you know when is $\Phi_n$ irreducible over $\mathbf F_{p^k}$? Thanks.

Comment: @caffeinemachine : have a look to [this](http://www.usthb.dz/fmath/IMG/pdf/cours_du_professeur_michel_waldschmidt_finite_fields_2014_1_.pdf#page=28), for instance corollary 48 (here $q=p^r$, as written just before theorem 41).